# How to move text between <li> left past the bullets

Tags: html, list

When I insert some `Text` between two `list items`, the `Text` is aligned with the *text* of the `list items` and thus looks as if it were part of the preceding `list item`.

How do I get the `Text` inserted between two `list items` to be aligned with the *bullet* of the  `list items` or, better yet, to stick out a bit.

This is about the plainest of plain html. (I am really a user of LaTeX---where I know how to do it!)

Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post an example or image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: There is no `Inter-Item-Text` in HTML. What are you referring to? Please post your HTML

Comment: @Sébastien Sorry about that: by `Inter-Item-Text`, I just meant some text I want inserted between two `list items`. (But in fact, `\interitemtext` is a LaTeX macro that was written a long time ago by Michel Bovani.) I have just edited my question according to @Martin Sikmund and yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than you probaply need is to define two lists and between them insert the text your want.

```html
<ul>
<li>item1 from list1</li>
</ul>
Between two lists
<ul>
<li>item1 from list2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Indeed, can't  make it plainer `html`! But why couldn't I think of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert text between two list items in HTML, you will produce invalid HTML. But what may be worse is that you will have a heard time styling it  because there would be no clear way in CSS to target that content

#### Invalid

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    Some other text
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

#### Solution

You can however create 2 separate lists and inbetween use any HTML you want. You can also use paragraphs inside list items, or even embed lists in inside list items.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1
    <p>More text as part of the list item</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<p>Some other text</p>

<ul>
  <li>Item 2 contains another list
    <ul>
      <li>item 2a</li>
      <li>item 2b</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```